# Optional regex groups in a makefile

Tags: regex, makefile

I try to test an input with regex, but it doesn't work.

Makefile:

```
test:
    if [[ "$(version)" =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)?$  ]]; then \
        echo "yes"; \
    else \
        echo "no"; \
    fi
```

Tests:

1. make test version="0.1.1"

   > yes

   It's ok.
2. make test version="0.1.1-S"

   > yes

   It's ok.
3. make test version="0.1.1-"

   > yes

   Should be no.
4. make test version="0.1.1-***"

   > yes

   Should be no.

When i remove '?':

```
^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)$
```

it works for cases #2, #3 and #4, but obviously doesn't work for case #1.

> $ make --version
>
> GNU Make 3.81
>
> …
>
> This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0

Where is my mistake?

Comment: regex seems to be correct :- https://regex101.com/r/lG5cZ3/1

Comment: A simpler regex with `non capturing` group will be `^\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?$`

Comment: @rock321987 yes, it was a specific behavior of make

Comment: \d doesn't work in a Makefile :)

Comment: didn't knew about it..change it to `[0-9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the $ with $$

```
 ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)?$$
```

$ in the makefile is special, so you need to escape the $, without escape your real regex will become

```
^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)?
```